# Chrome rendering of UTF-8

Tags: linux, google-chrome

When looking for Shruggie, I see an encoding error / rectangle box, instead of the wanted character. Strange enough: when I right-click and use the `search-for` option, the character is rendered correctly.

How can I fix the encoding, such, that I see the correct rendered shruggie?

Chrome Version: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

OS: openSuse Tumbleweed (if that is of any help)

[image: Shruggie]

[image: Shruggie in Google Search]

Comment: This might be due to the font selected not including the Japanese kana glyph in question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Interestingly, this was not always the case and I can't rember willingly changed my encoding settings or something like that. And Firefox does it correct ...  first (wild) guess was something within chrome has changed (?) or there is some "hidden" setting to set the encoding correct. But there are no settings for that.

Comment: Did you perhaps change the _font_ - e.g., from Times to Bookman, or Helvetica to Akzidenz-Grotesk, or something like that?

Comment: Font Settings: Standard: Times New Roman, Serif: Times New Roman, Sans-Serif Arial, and Monospace. Seems pretty common.

Comment: Hmmm... TNR, if it's the same TNR that comes with Windows, is a Unicode font, and does have the glyph; ditto Arial.

Comment: Hm. Perhaps I should copy the fonts from a Windows box. I use a package called fetchmsttcorefonts which itself pulls fonts off from sourceforge. https://software.opensuse.org/package/fetchmsttfonts

Comment: there's no such thing as *UTF-8 glyph*. UTF-8 is an encoding scheme for Unicode and each Unicode code point may be represented by a glyph

Comment: Title edited accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mystery is somehow solved. I had installed "Arial" which came with said `software.opensuse.org/package/fetchmsttfonts` Package. I copied over some fonts from old Windows installations and there was a font called `Arial Unicode MS`.

Switching to this *unicode capable* version solved the problem.